# jquery select() problem in IE(8)

Tags: jquery

jquery's select() is not working in IE, but its working fine in Firefox and Chrome.

What may be the problem with select() in IE, particulary IE8?

Comment: @Prasad, what are you trying to do with the `.select()` method? In jQuery it simply fires the `select` event. Can you describe how you are using it and what it isn't doing in IE8?

Comment: i have checkbox and a textbox. When the checkbox is checked, i need to enable the textbox and set the focus to the textbox and select the content in the textbox

Comment: @Prasad can you visit http://jsbin.com/osaka in IE8 and see if it selects the text box contents? I tested it in IE8 on XP and it worked fine. I wonder if something else is going on.

Comment: Its working fine when i use it in $(document).ready. But when i call it on checkbox change, its not selecting and the focus is still on checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IDEA 1**

Try adding a click trigger to your checkbox:

```
$(selector_to_checkbox).click(function(){ $(this).change() });
```

It is possible IE isn't properly triggering the change event.

**IDEA 2**

Try explicitly blurring the checkbox before calling `.select`

```
$(selector_to_checkbox).change(function(){
    $(this).blur();
    $(selector_to_textbox).select();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the hints @dcneiner, its the problem with the change event of checkbox in IE.